# c# How to stop console from displaying "..." whilst StreamWriter copies large amounts of data from a DataTable

Tags: c#, console, streamwriter

I have a console app that takes hundreds of small files, puts them into a temporary DataTable and then copies the data to a single StreamWriter. That works fine.

However, the console output continually adds "..." during the StreamWriter copy process, which is a bit annoying.

Is there any way to turn this off, or just replace it with something else, suck as a blinking "."?

Here's a cut down version of the code being used:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Writing to TA_{0}", fileType);
            var streamMaster = new StreamWriter(Settings.WorkingDirectory + "TA_" + fileType, true);
            streamMaster.Flush();

            foreach (var tempFile in filesList)
            {
                var isZipped = tempFile.Contains(".gz");
                var dtTempFile = InternalUtils.GetTable(tempFile, isZipped);

                foreach (DataRow row in dtTempFile.Rows)
                {
                    if(dtTempFile.Rows.IndexOf(row) != 0) streamMaster.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
                }
                streamMaster.Write(dtTempFile.Copy());

                dtTempFile.Dispose();
            }

            streamMaster.Close();
            streamMaster.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("TA_{0} Complete", fileType);
```

The output looks a lot like this:

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VD4S.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code in your listing that writes to the console...

Comment: There isn't, which is the weird part! I assumed it was something to do with the StreamWriter Class :/

Comment: Where you are writing "..." on console?

Comment: Either your listing is incomplete, or someone isn't playing nice with Single Responsibility. Take a look at `InternalUtils.GetTable`. There are plenty of programmers out there who just shove code anywhere to "make things work".

Comment: Does seem quite an odd behaviour Aron's suggestion is probably a good one.

Otherwise you could
It seems to be a weird consequence 

I suppose you if you just wanted to hide the output you could temporarily redirect the Console Output whilst it is loading the file using Console.SetOut or something while the code is writing those dots and switch back at the end ( I guess)

Comment: Find in project: `Console.Write(".`

Comment: Turns out I completely overlooked one line within the InternalUtils... Several dependencies in and I found:            If m_intRecord Mod 1000 = 0 Then
                Console.Write(".")
            End If

Comment: @Dezzamondo: Please consider deleting the question as it has no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For progress you could show `Console animation` for the purpose. Which deals with few symbol like `|`   `/` slash etc. You could set cursor position to spin it like animation.

```
  Console.WriteLine("Writing to TA_{0}", fileType);
  using(var streamMaster = new StreamWriter(Settings.WorkingDirectory + "TA_" + fileType, true))
   {     
       streamMaster.Flush();
       int counter = 0;

       foreach (var tempFile in filesList)
       {
            ShowAnimation(++counter);
            var isZipped = tempFile.Contains(".gz");
            var dtTempFile = InternalUtils.GetTable(tempFile, isZipped);

            foreach (DataRow row in dtTempFile.Rows)
            {
                if(dtTempFile.Rows.IndexOf(row) != 0) 
                    streamMaster.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
            }
            streamMaster.Write(dtTempFile.Copy());
            dtTempFile.Dispose();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("TA_{0} Complete", fileType);
```

**ShowAnimation Method**:

```
public void ShowAnimation (int counter)
{              
    switch (counter % 4)
    {
        case 0: Console.Write("/"); break;
        case 1: Console.Write("-"); break;
        case 2: Console.Write("\\"); break;
        case 3: Console.Write("|"); break;
    }
    Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hassan, I might replace the guys code with this instead :)

Comment: Why did you post this code. It doesn't answer the question

Comment: @musefan. It fulfill requirements. I focused on this line by OP `Is there any way to turn this off, or just replace it with something else, such as a blinking "."?`

Comment: @HassanNisar: I dunno.. the question is "why does it do this" and the answer is due to some code that isn't even included in the question. It's not a very good question in my opinion

Comment: @musefan. Yes you are right. Please suggest, should I delete the answer?

Comment: @HassanNisar: Don't worry about it, OP (or the community) can decide if the question remains or not. You are not to blame for trying to be helpful, I was just suggesting that the answer doesn't really seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a function several layers in that did this...

```
        If m_intRecord Mod 1000 = 0 Then
            Console.Write(".")
        End If
```

I must have completely overlooked it! Whoops!

Comment: That's what happens when you write in VB.Net